# Interactive bin/figure for bin packing with Painter in py3dbp

Tags: python, pyqt5, bin-packing

I have the simple bin packing code from enzoruiz and jerry800416 that takes in a list of items and packs them into a container.

```
from py3dbp import Packer, Bin, Item, Painter
import pandas as pd
import random
from PackagingGUI import PackageGUI

packer = Packer()
# Define the container dimensions (length, width, height)
conex = Bin("Conex Container", (120, 96, 102),10000,0,0)
packer.addBin(conex)

# Load item details from Excel file
item_list = "C:/Users/ParsonsJS/Container Stuff/Spares carton dimensions.xlsx" 
item_df = pd.read_excel(item_list)

# Adjust df to fit Item class with appropriate columns
# Define the columns to check for existence
columns_to_check = ['Importance', 'Loadbear', 'Updown', 'Color', 'Typeof']

# Check if columns exist and add them if they don't
for column in columns_to_check:
    if column not in item_df.columns:
        if column == 'Importance':
            item_df[column] = 1
        elif column == 'Loadbear':
            item_df[column] = 100
        elif column == 'Updown':
            item_df[column] = 'TRUE'
        elif column == 'Typeof':
            item_df[column] = 'cube'
        elif column == 'Color':
            num_rows = len(item_df)
            colors = ['#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(num_rows)]
            item_df[column] = colors

# Create the WHD tuple column from Final Length, Width, and Height
item_df['WHD'] = item_df.apply(lambda row: (row['Final Length'], row['Final Height'], row['Final Width']), axis=1)

# Add each part to the packer
for index, row in item_df.iterrows():
    item = Item(row['Part #'], row['Name'], row['Typeof'], row['WHD'], row['Unit weight'], row['Importance'], row['Loadbear'], row['Updown'], row['Color'])
    if not item.getVolume().is_nan():
        packer.addItem(item)
    else:
        print(row["Name"] + " has no Shipping dimensions")

# calculate packing 
packer.pack(
    bigger_first=True,
    distribute_items=False,
    fix_point=True,
    check_stable=True,
    support_surface_ratio=0.75,
    number_of_decimals=2
)


# put order
packer.putOrder()

# print result
b = packer.bins[0]
print("***************************************************")
for idx,b in enumerate(packer.bins) :
    print("**", b.string(), "**")
    print("***************************************************")
    print("FITTED ITEMS:")
    print("***************************************************")
    volume = b.width * b.height * b.depth
    volume_t = 0
    volume_f = 0
    weight_t = 0
    unfitted_name = ''
    for item in b.items:
        print("partno : ",item.partno)
        print("color : ",item.color)
        print("position : ",item.position)
        print("rotation type : ",item.rotation_type)
        print("W*H*D : ",str(item.width) +' * '+ str(item.height) +' * '+ str(item.depth))
        print("volume : ",float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
        print("weight : ",float(item.weight))
        volume_t += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
        weight_t += float(item.weight)
        print("***************************************************")
    
    print('space utilization : {}%'.format(round(volume_t / float(volume) * 100 ,2)))
    print('residual volumn : ', float(volume) - volume_t )
    print("gravity distribution : ",b.gravity)
    print('total weight of container:', weight_t)
    print("***************************************************")
    # draw results
    painter = Painter(b)
    fig = painter.plotBoxAndItems(
        title=b.partno,
        alpha=0.9,
        write_num=False,
        fontsize=10
    )

print("***************************************************")
print("UNFITTED ITEMS:")
for item in packer.unfit_items:
    volume_f += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    unfitted_name += '{},'.format(item.name)
#     print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print('unpack item : ',unfitted_name)
print('unpack item volumn : ',volume_f)

# fig.show()

# Add List GUI
list_gui = PackageGUI.setupUi(b.items)
deb=1
```

Everything works like it should with this portion of the code, but now I want to take it a step further and be able to interact with the figure.  I am looking at using PyQT5 that will display a list next to the figure which will highlight which colored box belongs to that item in the container.  I am unable to get the widget to read in any of the packer items and display them on the figure.  PyQT might not be the best option, but any sort of help on viewing what item is where in the container would be very helpful.  Ideally, when someone selects an item in the list, the boxes in the container will be greyed out besides the box corresponding to the item selected, that item's color will remain visible.
[image: ContainerImage]

This figure is good, an interactive list view next to it is the end product

Comment: It seems that the for you're using (which you should consider linking in your post so that we don't have to find it) uses matplotlib, so you should look into it with its Qt integration, in order to display figures within a QApplication.

Comment: Looking further into the py3dbp/Painter class it does appear to be using matplotlib so using that with pyqt should work eventually.  I will look at the QApplication, I had not looked into that yet, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that in order to add a figure to a Qt UI you need to use matplotlib's `qt-agg` integration, so that you can add Qt widget based figures.